# System.MissingMethodException Method not found : NET5 / NET48

Tags: c#, .net-5, webapi, .net-4.8

It might be a dumb question but here is my issue.
I'm developing a NET5 API that is referencing a NET Standard 2.0 assembly.
This Net Standard assembly references a NET48 assembly.
At runtime, I ran into an error message like this:

> System.MissingMethodException   HResult=0x80131513   Message=Method
> not found: 'System.String System.String.Concat(System.Object,
> System.Object, System.Object, System.Object, ...)'.

Nothing more in the Stacktrace except the line into the NET48 assembly where the exception occurs.
Eventually, I started over my API dev in NET48 and the problem is solved.
It seems to be a compatibility issue but I'm not sure I get the point.
Could you please explain what's wrong as I thought NET5 API would work with this reference?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's quite hard to understand exactly what's going on just from your description. Can you provide a [mcve]? (A console app referring to class libraries would probably be ideal.)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer but I can't share anything more at that point. And I can't reproduce the same issue without including the company dll. I'll dig deeper if any dependency is responsible for the issue.

Answer (score -2):

This error can occur when you try to use reflection in a project that is compiling to machine code.